# Android AdMob in different countries

Tags: android, admob, ads

How does AdMob work with apps being released in other countries?  I would think it would only help generate revenue with ads but is AdMob against it for some reason?  I am not sure if I should release my free app with AdMob ads in it for US only or have it be multiple countries.  Does anyone have any opinions or experiencewith this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admob has no country limitation or differentiation. It is based on what countries you have published your app is the countries can see your Admob ads. The ads language will be selective automatically either English or local languages based on mobile settings or user account settings, this is what Admob handles.

I am using it for long time in my free apps.

Herewith if your concern is about the Admob payment account and currency, you can change it through your account.

1. Sign in to your AdMob account at https://apps.admob.com.
2. Go to  > Payments > Payment settings.
3. In the Account information section, click change country.
4. Click Continue.

Comment: so then the revenue in other countries would be converted to USD?

Comment: yes, every click has its own calculation. and its revenue will be converted to your selected account such as USD.